# Windows 7,8 dual boot- winload.exe error: "could not verify digital signature error"

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bootloader, mbr, bcd

I've a Asus G73Sw that has Windows7 Home pre-installed. I recently added a new 120GB SSD and installed windows 8.1 on it. Everything was fine till recently when the original Win7 on my other HDD, got sluggish, and thus I decided to restore it back to factory version. So, using the built-in ASUS recovery option (by tapping F9 on boot), I successfully went through the recovery process and win7 restoration using the in-built system-image was successful.

But then, I lost my win8.1 boot option on OS select step (which was expected). So, I used *Easy BCD* and added a new boot entry. The option now re-appeared. But when trying to launch win8.1 , I now get:

**"Winload.exe error: could not verify digital signature"**
AFAIK, the boot guid is different which is why this maybe happening (but this is just my guess).

So, now I don't know what to do. I don't want to throw away everything on Win8.1. I even tried "Automatically Fix MBR" option of *Visual BCD Editor*, but still nothing happens. So, what I'm looking for is suggestion of any tool or manual process to fix my broken MBR record. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Automatic Repair" option in [Dual-boot Repair tool](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-tool-for-windows-8.1-update.html) should work. Give it a try.

The problem would be solved when Windows 8 boot manager is on active partition, first disk in case of MBR style disk or on EFI System partition in case of GPT style disk.

You are trying to load Windows 8.1 using Windows 7 boot manager which gives the error message about failure of digital signature verification. Windows 7 boot manager cannot know about Windows 8 digital signatures.